# inplace deletion of a line before and after a pattern using sed command in linux

Tags: shell, sed

```
forward-zone:
name: "."
forward-addr: 10.1.1.2

forward-zone:
name: "mydomain.com"
forward-addr: 10.1.1.1
```

I wanted to delete one line before the pattern 'name: "."' and one line after the pattern (including the pattern itself). I tried the following command but this is not modifying the file itself. I want to do inplace modification. Please help

```
sed -n '/name: "."/{N;s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' file
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed` ?  `sed` is good for modifications in range of one line. When you want to delete next line because the previous is smth, it's better (more readable) to move to `awk`. To modify the file you should use the `-i` option with `sed`. Or pipe to a temporary file and move, or use `sponge`.

Comment: @kamilCuk Can you please let me know how I can use awk in this scenario?

Comment: `perl -i -00 -ne 'print unless /^name: "\."/m'`

Comment: @melpomene your solution deletes the following section as well           
    forward-zone:
    name: "mydomaim.com"
    forward-addr: 10.1.1.2

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://tio.run/##dYwxDsIwDEX3nMLKkilpwpizIKTQGLVSbVcOCBVx98DQbqC/Pb33r6VNveM4Cbib6LNo9S9hzIYLYQYbrDl4qVUzpBjSdydjfvq0VaEycxiF/qTJwRtW1AV8jOAZwa068x0evGBrMFz2r3OwA7nePw).

Comment: I like your question. To achieve this using `sed` seems challenging. (To use `awk` would probably be easier, but the `sed` question is interesting.)

Comment: @melpomene How can I use your solution to make in place modification of a file. I tried `perl -i -00 -ne 'print unless /^name: "\."/m' <filename>`. It deleted the mydomain part also.

Comment: @thb I tried using awk `awk '/name: "."/{for(x=NR-1;x<=NR+1;x++)d[x];}{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)if(!(i in d))print a[i]}' <file-name>` . But it doesn't do in place modification.

Comment: @SumanShil Then your input file doesn't contain what you've shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might suit.

```
sed -rne '/^name: "\."/{n;n;h;d};1{h;d};x;p;${g;p}' -i file
```

The `-i` option lets Sed modify the file in place. The Sed commands `h`, `g` and `x` use Sed's *hold space* to hold the previous line until the current line has been examined. The addresses `1` and `$` respectively treat the file's first and last lines, which probably want special handling.

Though this has been an educational exercise, admittedly, Awk or even Perl might be a better tool than Sed for such multiline processing. Nevertheless, with some extra effort, Sed can do the job, as you see.

Comment: If you have found the answer useful, then, besides *accepting* it with the green checkmark, you can also *upvote* it with the orange arrow.

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk way:

```
$ awk '$2!~/name:\s*\"."/' RS= FS="\n" file
forward-zone:
name: "mydomain.com"
forward-addr: 10.1.1.1
```

Since GNU awk 4.1.0 you can add switch `-i inplace` to change file inplace.
So that would be:

```
awk -i inplace '$2!~/name:\s*\"."/' RS= FS="\n" file
```